# What are the words?

Tags: word

From 5 words, a single letter has been removed and remaining letters bunched together in order. The number in the bracket represents the length of the word. For example:

SEVENTEEN  = SVNTN (9)  Single letter E removed

Can you identify the words?

1  **ILE (7)**

2  **AIN (7)**

3  **OUIO (8)**

4  **PIA (7)**

5  **AIET (8)**

No partial answers please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think these are valid answers, but there might be better options for one or two of these.

1 ILE (7)

> diddled

2 AIN (7)

> gagging

3 OUIO (8)

> nonunion

4 PIA (7)

> pizzazz

5 AIET (8)

> sassiest

Comment: You beat me to it, that's what I found too

Comment: Great Job @Jaap Scherphuis